# Две формы в одной модели DJANGO

Tags: django

Всем привет! Есть модель Patient поля, которой должны заполняться на двух страницах. Как сделать так, чтобы модель Patient полностью заполнилась при введённых на двух страницах данных?

На данный момент не могу сделать редирект на динамический адрес второй страницы.

**Модель**

```
class Patient(models.Model):
surname_patient             = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Фамилия пациента')
name_patient                = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Имя пациента')
middlename_patient          = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Отчество пациента')
birthday_patient            = models.DateField(max_length=50, verbose_name='День рождение пациента')
gender_patient              = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Пол пациента')
enlightenment_patient       = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Санитарное просвящение пациента')
number_of_medical_card      = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Номер медицинской карты', null=False)
symptoms_patient            = models.ManyToManyField('Symptom', verbose_name="Симптомы", related_name = 'symptoms_patient' , blank=True)
childhood_diseases          = models.ManyToManyField('Disease', verbose_name="Болезни детства", related_name = 'childhood_diseases', blank=True)
relatives_diseases          = models.ManyToManyField('Disease', verbose_name="Болезни у родственников", related_name = 'relatives_diseases', blank=True)
chronic_disease             = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Хронические заболевания', null=True)
```

**Формы**

*Форма 1*

```
class PatientFIOForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Patient
    fields = ['surname_patient', 'name_patient', 'middlename_patient', 'number_of_medical_card', 'birthday_patient', 'gender_patient', 'enlightenment_patient']

    widgets = {
        "surname_patient": TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'input_text',
        }),

        "name_patient": TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'input_text',
        }),

        "middlename_patient": TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'input_text',
        }),

        "number_of_medical_card": TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'input_text',
        })
    }
```

*Форма 2*

```
class PatientProcessForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Patient
    fields = ['symptoms_patient', 'childhood_diseases', 'relatives_diseases', 'chronic_disease']

    widgets = {
        "symptoms_patient": SelectMultiple(attrs={
            'class': 'input_text process'
        }),

        "childhood_diseases": SelectMultiple(attrs={
            'class': 'input_text process'
        }),

        "relatives_diseases": SelectMultiple(attrs={
            'class': 'input_text process'
        }),

        "chronic_disease": Textarea(attrs={
        'class': 'input_text process',
        })
    }
```

**Вьюшки**

```
class PersonalToProcessRedirectView(RedirectView):

def personal_data(request):
    error = ''
    elements = Patient.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PatientFIOForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            error = 'Возникла ошибка'
    form = PatientFIOForm()
    context = {'elements': elements, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'app/diagnost_fio.html', context)

def get_redirect_url(self, pk):
    return reverse('process', args=(pk,))


class processView(View):

def get(self, request, pk):
    patient = Patient.objects.get(pk=pk)
    elements = Patient.objects.all()
    form = PatientProcessForm()
    context = {'form': form,'elements': elements,'patient': patient}
    return render(request, 'app/diagnost_process.html', context)

def post(self, request, pk):
    patient = Patient.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = PatientProcessForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new = form.save()
        return redirect(new)
    form = PatientProcessForm()
    return render(request, 'app/diagnost_process.html', context = {'form': form})
```

**Url**

```
path('personal_data', views.PersonalToProcessRedirectView.as_view(), name='personal_data'),
path('process/<int:pk>', views.processView.as_view(), name='process'),
```

Answer (score 0):

`return redirect(new)`
нужно заменить на `return redirect(reverse('process', args=(new.pk,))`

я бы на твоем месте вместо `View` и `RedirectView` использовал `FormView` в обоих случаях, так как и там и там ты обрабатываешь данные формы, код будет проще, на мой взгляд